# PowerPoint 2013 changes colors in imported PowerPoint 2010 presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, import, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am helping someone out with an issue.

They have Office/Powerpoint 2010 on their desktop.  They will be out of town and have a company issued laptop with Office/Powerpoint 2013 on it.

When we imported the 2010 presentation into 2013 (by just opening it), several of the colors changed and some even disappeared.  FWIW, it was based on a CrystalGraphics macro-enhanced template.

Is there either some way to roll back the changes, or do a correct import,so we do not have to redo the presentation?

Comment: Is the CrystalGraphics macro-enhanced template on the work computer?

Comment: I do not believe so, as I didn't know it had to be.  I thought (not a PowerPoint person) that all the data would be embedded.